# Play 2.0 templating - Scala `match` and `val` do not compile in a view template

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, template-engine, playframework-2.0

I have the following code in Play 2.0 template:

```
@content.toString.lines.map{
    case line =>     // i put `case` here as another attempt to make it work
    line match {
        case "" => @Html("")
        case _ => <li>@Html(line)</li>   /*CRASH*/
    }   
}
```

It fails on the marked line, saying that `not found: value line`. The second variant of it:

```
@for(line <- content.toString.lines){
    @line match {                            /*CRASH*/
        case "" => @Html("")
        case _ => <li>@Html(line)</li>
    }   
}
```

fails on the marked line, claiming that `'case' expected but identifier found`.

**UPDATE:**

Same thing goes for `val`:

```
@val headID = "head"
```

comes up with `illegal start of simple expression`.

**UPDATE ENDS**

I would like to know, what am I doing wrong and how to correctly implement the `match-case` structure and `val` assignment in Play's templates?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Using `match` expressions in templates

You need to enclose in braces (“{” and “}”) the HTML content of your templates:

```html
@for(line <- content.toString.lines) {
  @line match {
    case "" => { }
    case _ => { <li>@Html(line)</li> }
  }
}
```

In your specific case, the following code would read better IMHO:

```html
@content.toString.lines.collect {
  case line if !line.isEmpty => { <li>@Html(line)</li> }
}
```

## Defining values

You can define values using the `defining[T](value: T)(usage: T => Html)` helper:

```html
@defining(1 + 2 * 3) { value =>
  <div>@value</div>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that add a {} outside to enclose entire code would work

```
@{content.toString.lines.map{ line => 
  line match {
    case "" =>  @Html("")
    case _ => <li>@Html(line)</li> 
}}
```

Comment: Lifesaver! After scratching my head for well over an hour on this one I found that this worked for me also. Totally unexpected as I have other files within the same project, practically identical in structure, that do not need this and the only possible difference is I'm using a field of a parameter being passed as opposed to a parameter being passed (@x.f versus @x) HOWEVER I edited the code and tried passing the param directly and it still would not compile. I though it might be .xml versus .html and that didn;t make a difference either. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: In a case of the beyond bizarre whatever I had started compiling all of a sudden -- it was erring WITH the (miracle cure) wrapped braces and then when I removed them the new errors went away but the entire file compiled cleanly. I quickly tried to back out all of the changes I had made in the last couple of hours or so to see if I could get a hit on the real culprit here but to no avail. I would suggest digging deeper if this happens to you as the braces somehow mask a deeper issue.

Answer (score 1):

following seems to work for me

```
@content.toString.lines.map{ line => 
    line match {
      case "" =>  @Html("")
     case _ => <li>@Html(line)</li> 
}
```

hard on eyes, but you can look at `target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/views/html/index.template.scala` in the play project directory to see what its putting in string literals.

As for val assignment, I don't know, but [@defining](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates) may help

Answer (score 0):

Another frequent cause of this error is to have the starting brace on a separate line:

```
@x match {
case y => 
  { //offending brace, put it back on the same line as case
  } //This can go anywhere
}
```